# Redirect to an another local page after receiving a message from an iframe in HTML

Tags: html, redirect, iframe, postmessage

I have a webpage with an form embedded in a iframe. I want once the form is submitted sends a message to the parent page and parent page goes to another local page. I know how to do the postmessage part, but I don´t know how could be code in parent page to redirect to a local page once receives the message.

Could someone help me with that code? thank you very much

So in this manner user would see a local page after submitting the form.

Comment: `<form target="_top" action="submitandredirect">`